# CorelDRAW - Remove a portion of a letter

Tags: corel-draw

I have a project in CorelDRAW that requires a change to the font. The font used has the letter "i" written as `|` and I need to turn it into `i`. How it has been done in the past is someone put a white box (line) through the middle, thereby adding a dot; however, this only works if the background is also white.

I want a transparent background so I would like a more flexible solution.

Can I erase part of the letter?
Can I add a transparent mask, so that the letter is covered, and the background shows through?

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can convert the text to curves and subtract the box from the I. The operation is named "Trim" in CDraw. You can retain the editability by having a hidden copy of the text as non-curved.

If you want to keep your textbox as text, but change I's appearance, you have the following options:

- Change the font to another with wanted I (You can easily make one, if you have a font editor, only edit one glyph)
- Replace I with a space and place another textbox or graphic shape with the wanted I over it